# Item removed from ArrayList, but notifyDataSetChanged() only deletes the bottom item

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view, with an ArrayList from custom objects.
Each row has a delete button, when clicked the item is deleted from the recyclerview.
Now the delete button works, and deletes the correct item from the arraylist, however when the items are displayed again in the list, only the bottom item is deleted, and the item which was really deleted from the list stays there.

Its really weird, and I cannot figure out why?

I manage the deleted item from the activity, here is the code of the activity:

```
public class ManageExerciseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "999.OffLimitsActivity";
private RecyclerView exerciseRecyclerView;
private ExerciseManageAdapter exerciseAdapter;
public ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_exercise);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ManageExerciseActivity.this, AddExerciseActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    fab.setImageBitmap(textAsBitmap("ADD", 40, Color.WHITE));


    exerciseList = new ArrayList<>();


        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Manage my exercises");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        exerciseRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.exercise_manage_recycler_view);
        exerciseAdapter = new ExerciseManageAdapter(exerciseList);


        exerciseAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExerciseManageAdapter.ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final int position, final View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick pos = " + position);

// custom dialog
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ManageExerciseActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Do you wish to delete this exercise?")
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            String itemRemoved = exerciseList.get(position).getNameOfExercise();

                            exerciseList.remove(position);

                            exerciseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                            Snackbar.make(v, itemRemoved + " deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("Undo", null).show();




                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            builder.create();
            builder.show();

        }
    });


    exerciseRecyclerView.setAdapter(exerciseAdapter);
    exerciseRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



}
```

and here is the adapter:

```
public class ExerciseManageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


    private static ClickListener clickListener;

    public ImageView exerciseItemIcon;
    public TextView exerciseNameTextView;
    public TextView exerciseDurationTextView;
    public TextView exerciseTimesRemainingTextView;
    public ImageView deleteImageView;

    ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ExerciseManageAdapter(ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseArrayList) {

        this.exerciseArrayList = exerciseArrayList;

    }


    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }


    class ExerciseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public ExerciseViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

//            view.setOnClickListener(this);

            exerciseNameTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_manage_name_textView);
            exerciseDurationTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_manage_duration_textview);
            exerciseTimesRemainingTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_manage_times_remaining);
            exerciseItemIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.exercise_manage_item_icon);
            deleteImageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_exercise_button);

            deleteImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }




        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }


    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        ExerciseManageAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            return position;
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return exerciseArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {



            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.exercise_manage_item_row, parent, false);



            return new ExerciseViewHolder(itemView);

        }




        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            ExerciseViewHolder exerciseViewHolder = (ExerciseViewHolder) holder;
            exerciseNameTextView.setText(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getNameOfExercise());
            exerciseDurationTextView.setText(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getDurationOfExercise());
            exerciseTimesRemainingTextView.setText(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getTimesPerWeek() + " times a week");
            exerciseItemIcon.setImageResource(exerciseArrayList.get(position).getExerciseIcon());


            }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.!

```
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mData.size());
```